# Implementing Captcha

Tags: javascript, php, email, captcha

I am trying to implement Captcha at a company I've just started working for. We currently have a website where each page has its own e-mail form. At the present time, it has PHP validating the fields for erroneous entries, but nothing to prevent spam from getting through.

I have tried implementing Recaptcha by Google, but the size of the image is too big to fit within the design (I am limited as to how drastically I can change things without a lot of confirmed approval). So simply, I need to get a simple PHP or JavaScript captcha script running that will block MOST of the spam.

The issues: I've tried a few scripts out there but keep running into issues, and can't seem to troubleshoot them. The biggest issue would be the fact that I cannot send myself test e-mails. I'm not entirely educated on the manner in which e-mail (re)direction works, but our e-mail forms get sent to the Support department in another State. Even if I re-enter the destination e-mail to my own work e-mail, I do not receive the e-mails, therefore it makes it difficult to determine whether the script is functioning or not.

I am also running into issues as to where placement of the script should be, relative to the already existing scripts.

Can anyone suggest a fairly easy Captcha, and possibly some solutions, or ways in which to sort out my "not receiving e-mails" dilemma?

Comment: Something simple some sites use that I've seen, is to show a simple question, like "what is two plus two?". Most bots won't be able to answer.

Comment: Maybe this one; not sure if fit your needs: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/asirra/

Comment: What are the test emails for? Would it suffice to stub out the email part of the code and dump something to the console or an alert box instead?

Comment: Hey Stevie, can you rephrase that? I didn't quite understand what you were suggesting. I wouldn't mind doing something simple, however I'm in a predicament where I wouldn't want to make big changes to something as crucial to the company as customer support, and not be able to verify that everything is functioning properly until it's too late - ie: "What the hell, support team isn't receiving any e-mails!"

Comment: Basically, by the sounds of things your Captcha code has nothing to do with sending emails. What I would do is find the method that is responsible for sending emails and add some debug code. For example, in addition to sending an email, also log the contents of the email to your debug console, so you can at least verify the content is still correct; what happens to the email along the way is an irrelevant redirection issue, as you describe it.

Comment: TBH, I can't even find a simple math captcha at this point. Each one I stumble across has a "verify" button. I'd just like it to either submit the e-mail if the response is correct, or redirect to an error page if not. I am really struggling with what I thought would be simple.